# In JSON schema, what does keyword "extends" mean

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

I got following piece of JSON schema, can someone explain the meaning of keyword "extends". I couldn't find it in the books etc.

```
{ 
"description" : "Human readable TSM-X radio alias, which is displayed in PLI streams", 
"extends" : { 
"minLength" : 1, 
"pattern" : "^[a-zA-Z0-9~,.?!/_+= -]*$" 
}, 
"maxLength" : 16, 
"type" : "string" 
}
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Out of interest, which books are you referring to?

Answer (score 3):

Wow, you've encountered a *very* old schema. `extends` used to be a JSON Schema keyword, but was removed in draft-04 (2013). Here's the draft-03 specification, good luck.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-zyp-json-schema-03

Answer (score 1):

JSON Schema doesn't define an `extends` keyword, but the library you're using may.

`extends` has been proposed as a way to define a sort of "base" schema to which other keywords could be appended.  However, in the end, the functionality was only marginally different than `allOf` while the semantics implied an inheritance model, which JSON Schema is definitely not.

Comment: Thanks,
you say, "extends" was or has been proposed so that additional properties can be appended to a base schema. But the example has only one property of type string.
And "extends" seem to be restricting the format of that string.

Comment: My point was that there has been discussion around the keyword and what it might mean, but it's not part of the specification.